# Does oozie use Yarn containers

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, cloudera-cdh

We are currently running a large amount of Oozie jobs in our cluster.

Many of those jobs use templates and have sub-workflows.

These jobs don't always contain large and heavy jobs, they mostly contain a small shell script.

The Hue job browser show lots and lots of Oozie steps.

We now sometimes feel that our cluster is getting overloaded by these jobs. This made me wonder, does every one of those Oozie jobs get a yarn container appointed to it?

If so this would mean that for a 2 min job we are effectively useing 2-10 times more resources than required.

Comment: What types of jobs? Mapreduce related tasks? If so, yes, those get an application master and all that stuff for each task. You could watch the ResourceManager UI to determine if those tasks are taking up YARN, though

Comment: mostly shell script wrappers and spark jobs

Comment: I'm not sure about shell scripts needing to communicate with YARN, but Spark can for definitely use a lot of memory

Comment: the shell wrappers are effectively starting jobs on their own, i.e. sqoop jobs etc. Some other jobs just append 1 line to a text file, ... so it differs. THe thing with the spark jobs is that it's straightforward to see what's what. So there we see how much it's using of our systems. It's the oozie containers that elude me.

Answer (score 1):

Just see by yourself...

- in the Hue Dashboard, click on any Workflow that has been executed, select the "Actions" tab, look at the "External ID" column => **every `job_000000_0000` refers to a YARN job**
- ...and when "External ID" points to a Sub-Workflow, then if you click, you will get its own YARN jobs
- alternately you can use the command line with `oozie job -info <wkf/sub-wkf exec id>`

You can get more details in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855616/why-do-my-application-level-logs-disappear-when-executed-in-oozie/38856067#38856067) for instance.

---

A frequent issue with Shell or Java actions is that the "launcher" YARN job uses the default job settings defined by your Hadoop admin -- e.g. 1 GB of RAM for the AppMaster and 1.5 GB for the "launcher".
But typically your shell just requires a few MB of RAM *(on top of what is used by Oozie to bootstrap the Action in a raw YARN container)*, and its AppMaster just requires the bare minimum to control the execution-- say, 512 MB each.

So **you can reduce the footprint of your Oozie actions** by setting some **undocumented properties** -- in practice, standard Hadoop props prefixed by `oozie.launcher.`
See for instance [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262896/oozie-shell-action-memory-limit/24262996#24262996) then [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961310/oozie-java-action-why-property-oozie-launcher-mapred-child-java-opts-does-no/34005795#34005795).

PS: `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.java.opts` is relevant for a Java action (or a Pig action, a Sqoop action, etc.) and should stay consistent with the global RAM quota; but it's not relevant for a Shell action *[unless you set a really goofy value, in which case it might affect the Oozie bootstrap process]*

Answer (score 0):

In your case **Yes**, all jobs will get container still if you are invoking MR through shell. Its not true that for each container **YARN** will provide unnecessary memory or resources.

Yarn provides exact or little more resources but it increases if Job requires more.

Comment: Yarn always provides a minimum of preconfigured memory to a job, in most cases around 1GB, so this seems untrue