# Is it possible to limit number of oozie workflows running at the same time?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, oozie, cloudera-cdh

This is not clear to me from the [docs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/#Developer_Documentation).  Here's our scenario and why we need this as succinctly as I can:

We have 60 coordinators running, launching workflows usually hourly, some of which have sub-workflows (some multiple in parallel).  This works out to around 40 workflows running at any given time.  However when cluster is under load or some underlying service is slow (e.g. impala or hbase), workflows will run longer than usual and back up so we can end up with 80+ workflows (including sub-workflows) running.

This sometimes results in ALL workflows hanging indefinitely, because we have only enough memory and cores allocated to this pool that oozie can start the launcher jobs (i.e. `oozie:launcher:T=sqoop:W=JobABC:A=sqoop-d596:ID=XYZ`), but not their corresponding actions (i.e. `oozie:action:T=sqoop:W=JobABC:A=sqoop-d596:ID=XYZ`).

We could simply allocate enough resources to the pool to accommodate for these spikes, but that would be a massive waste (hundreds of cores and GBs that other pools/tenants could never use).

So I'm trying to enforce some limit on number of workflows running, even if that means some will be running behind sometimes.  BTW all our coordinators are configured with execution=LAST_ONLY, and any delayed workflow will simply catch up fully on the next run.  We are on CDH 5.13 with Oozie 4.1; pools are setup with DRF scheduler.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: What about distinct queues for launcher jobs, with a hard limit on available resources matching e.g. 30*2 containers (AM+mapper), and for the spawned YARN jobs, with much more resources?

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438052/job-queue-for-hive-action-in-oozie/32438566 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961310/oozie-java-action-why-property-oozie-launcher-mapred-child-java-opts-does-no

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not a configuration parameter that let you control the number of workflows running at a given time.

If your coordinators are scheduled to run approximately in the same time-window, you could think to collapse them in just one coordinator/workflow and use the fork/join control nodes to control the degree of parallelism. Thus you can distribute your actions in a K number of queues in your workflow and this will ensure that you will not have more than K actions running at the same time, limiting the load on the cluster.
We use a script to generate automatically the fork queues inside the workflow and distribute the actions (of course this is only for actions that can run in parallel, i.e. there no data dependencies etc).

Hope this helps